# How to decode in JavaScript/Node.js a string of combined UTF16 and normal characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, utf-16

I have a huge JSON stringified into a string like this one:

`"\\u007B\\u0022name\\u0022\\u003A\\u0022T\\u0065st\\u0022}"`

I need to JSON.parse it to use as an object. Do you know any way to decode it?

I tried `decodeURIComponent()`, `unescape()`, different variants of `.replace( /\\u/g, "\u" )` and I can not get it into the needed form.

Comment: If it's a legal JSON formatted string, just call `JSON.parse()` on it.  It should handle the UTF encoding for you and give you back a Javascript string.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert UTF-16 to text using the following function:

```
function utf16ToText(s) {
  return s.replace(/\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/gi, match => {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ""), 16));
  });
}
```

***Demo:***

```js
const r = utf16ToText("\\u007B\\u0022name\\u0022\\u003A\\u0022T\\u0065st\\u0022\\u007d");
console.log("As text: ", r);

const j = JSON.parse(r);
console.log("As JSON: ", j);

console.log("JSON Prop: ", j.name);

function utf16ToText(s) {
  return s.replace(/\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/gi, match => {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ""), 16));
  });
}
```

Comment: But the JSON format allows UTF16 formatting so shouldn't `JSON.parse()` handle the parsing of the UTF16 for you just fine?

Comment: @jfriend00 if the [string were formatted correctly it works](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/wvBKYmJ?editors=1011), but for some reason, even when [cleaning up the formatting](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/Bayoqrp?editors=1011) it doesn't work.

Comment: What about this: https://codepen.io/jfriend00/pen/rNaOqJZ?editors=1011?

Comment: @jfriend00 - aahhhh! I see what you did there. BRILLIANT! I learned something today, thanks a lot. Cheers!!

Comment: @jfriend00 how can you accomplish this using a variable? https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/ExaVdRr?editors=1011 - if OP is getting the UTF-16 data from an API or reading the contents from a file, etc..., he won't have the opportunity to wrap in single quotes, the data he receives will live inside some variable.. right?..or am I missing something?

Comment: [I figured it out](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/povjQEQ?editors=1011) using your method.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that to be legal JSON (that will work with `JSON.parse()`) it has to be double quote delimited.  The actual string needs to contain the quotes.  So, part of the OP's issue is that their string isn't legal JSON.  So, in your example you could have also done `JSON.parse('"' + y + '"')` to add the quotes to the string on either end.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's the last thing I can't seem to figure out (outside of the function I made above) - how do you turn just a regular UTF16 string into text? [Is there a better way to unescape the duplicate backslashes?](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/povjQEQ?editors=1011).. Bothers me that I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: @MattOestreich - I finally just posted an answer myself that shows how to do it using only `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought I tried that (unsuccessfully) with a plain ol string, but I guess I was being sloppy during my testing.. [I just tried it](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/XWJmoaM?editors=1011) again, and it looks like you can use your method with just a plain string. I really appreciate all of your input - thank you for putting up with my questions lol! I def learned something today. Again, thanks so much! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is valid JSON, then you can use `JSON.parse()` to process the UTF16 for you.  To make what you have valid JSON, you have to add double quotes to each end (inside the actual string) as all strings must be enclosed in double quotes in the JSON format.  Here's an example:

```js
let data = "\\u007B\\u0022name\\u0022\\u003A\\u0022T\\u0065st\\u0022\\u007d";
// to make this legal JSON so we can let the JSON parser parse it for us and 
// handle the UTF16 for us, we need to put double quotes in the actual string at each end 
// Then, it's legal JSON and we can parse it
let str = JSON.parse('"' + data + '"');
console.log(str);
console.log("type is", typeof str);
```

This gives you a result in **string** form:

```
{"name":"Test"}
```

This result is now legal JSON on its own.  If you then wanted to parse that as JSON, could just call `JSON.parse()` on it again to turn it into an actual Javascript object:

```js
let data = "\\u007B\\u0022name\\u0022\\u003A\\u0022T\\u0065st\\u0022\\u007d";
let str = JSON.parse('"' + data + '"');   // decoded string here

// now take the string and actually parse it into a Javascript object 
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);   // Javascript object here
console.log("type is", typeof obj);
```

This gives you a resulting live Javascript object:

```
{name:"Test"}
```

The first call to `JSON.parse()` just takes your JSON string and decodes it into a Javascript string.  Since that Javascript string is now also legal JSON for an object definition, you can call `JSON.parse()` on it again to turn it into a Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. Because of that, I got the solution:

`let a = "\\u007B\\u0022name\\u0022\\u003A\\u0022T\\u0065st\\u0022}"` original string

`let b = '"' + a + '"'` adding " in order to make a valid stringified JSON

`let c = JSON.parse(b)` that will produce a partially decoded string (partially because some of the \uXXXX characters can stay in the string)

`let solution = JSON.parse(c)` that will create an object with all the characters decoded

**Big thanks to @jfriend00**

Comment: How is this any differente from @jfriend00 answer.

Comment: It is not, but his wasn't posted as an answer, so I wanted to place it in a very visible place - if I did something wrong, sorry :(